# Drag events not firing on Android N

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-7.0-nougat

Editing for unmarking as duplicate:

I have an app that uses many drag and drop capabilities.
I have different fragments that can replace one another and respond to drags that started in different fragments.

For that I use what we call a *main drag listener* that is set to the outer layout element, and dispatches drag events for the different components as needed, depending on the location of the drag event.

Everything worked well, until I tested my app with Android N.
Now I am getting only `drag started and drag ended events` but No drag location or drag dropped.

It seems as if some other view is intercepting the drag events, but I have no Idea how to check for that, besides setting a drag listener for each and every view in the app and logging it.

I saw there were some changes in the Drag-Drop mechanism in Android N, to prepare it for the inter-app interaction, but I couldn't see anything that might affect me.

**EDIT:**

I don't think this is a duplicate as suggested.
My app works well on devices with API < 24. Unless some default or other behavior changed in API 24

**EDIT 2:**

```
irrelevant
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
irrelevant
```

**EDIT 4:**

As I claimed before, this is not a duplicate of the proposed issue. Mainly because it happens only on Android N. Further more, it seems like a bug in Android 7.0 as mentioned [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/29/psa-drag-drop-behavior-change-Android-7p0.html) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=221012).

I will look into the proposal in the CommonsBlog post and will report here my conclusions

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't think this is a duplicate since everything works well on devices with API < 24. Unless some default or other behavior changed in API 24.

Comment: @YvetteColomb see Edit 2